# Easy Android Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an android app in eclipse and for some reason the .AgainActivity is always launching rather than .Splash. I deleted the .AgainActivity and ran it in the emulator AND the .Splash worked, but it will not run first when both activities are present.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

AndroidManifest XML:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/test_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".AgainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="again.we.practice.AgainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Splash Java:

```
package again.we.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle National) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(National);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full manifest file, including the package declaration? I cannot reproduce your error based on what you posted. Android should start the activity that has the launcher intent, which in my case it does. What is the use of the intent in the other activity? Can't you just leave that intent out? I only use intents when I need them, like for launching and catching intents from other apps. Or did you edit your question after the first answer below?

Comment: I am not sure which file you want me to post. I removed the intents and it wouldn't launch at all. When I remove the whole .AgainActivity it launches correctly.

Comment: The manifest file you posted is not complete. It should have these lines: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` is correct according to it Splash `Activity` should display first since it is intended as main.

Or just try removing `<intent-filter>` for `AgainActivity` as below,

```
<activity android:name=".AgainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it wouldn't launch when I did that

Comment: Because i tried creating 2 activity Splash and AgainActitity. For which Splash was loaded first. Try to uninstall the app. from you emulator and deploy it again.

Comment: I have been trying to run it via Eclipse and it hasn't been working (as stated above) BUT I ran it from my emulator and it did work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure why it wouldn't run correctly from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your xml file where you have the first activity tag you have

```
    android:name = ".splash"
```

change that to the

```
    android:name = ".AgainActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the intent from the AgainActivity:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="again.we.practice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/test_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".AgainActivity">
     </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="again.we.practice"   //package name
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> //your minsdkversion level
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >        
      <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"  android:name=".Splash"   
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">    

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>            
        </activity>    
        <activity android:name = ".AgainActivity" />                         
</application>
```